# Unable to create debug build android studio after latest update

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Unable to create debug build since I have updated android studio and gradle

It is showing following error

```
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

`

I already have mutidex enabled and follwing are dexoptions

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Also in gradle.properties file I have added follwoing

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

But still **I am not able to create debug build and its taking to much time to compile project and show error**

I am using **Android Studio 2.1 beta 2 Build #AI-143.2765781**
And **com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta1** and gradle distrubution url is as follows distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Comment: Have you tried Clean your project before rebuilding?

Comment: yes I did infact i deleted whole build folder as well

Comment: Why not try revert back to Android Studio 2.0?

Comment: yes doing that I am re-installing it

Comment: Has this got solved after reinstalling?

Comment: yes it is working now after reinstalling